# VBA If giving false "true" response

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

HI Everyone I am struggling with a false true on a VBA - in short the system need to check one button needs to update a onepager sheet which indicate a Y or N for a market. to get to the yes or no a samples results need to be checked against the market's spec. I have created a user form to submit the results since there are more than 500 different actives which could be present however usually one less than 10 are detected. So i have a database sheet in which the actives are vertical and a one pager in which it is indicated which marketplace's database to use. I want to use the Userform's dropdown (Active1) to check which active are present and then have vba check that the result which is in the textbox (NewMRL1) against the relevant database which is indicated in a specific cells on the onepager (RelSh). I used the If in vba but the results come in as a false positive / false true. for example the country limit will be 5 while the value in NewMRL1 is 3. If i type the code for if 3 greater than 5 then msgbox ("above limit") then it gives the correct answer but the minute i start referring to the relevant values of the different sheets it gives a false positive. If i debug and hover over the values then it does give me the correct values to which are referred to. I have also changed the > and < to check if i did not have it the wrong way round but even that did not help he always gives a true back.  I have also changed the ranges checkups so please excuse the horible coding which is totally not neat! Here is my code please help!

your Assistance is much appreciated!

```
Private Sub Check_ResultsAgainstCry()

'Identify MRL country sheet
Dim MRLCry As Worksheet
Set MRLCry = Worksheets("MRL - Countries")

'Identify worksheet in which references should retrieved from
Dim RelSh As Worksheet
strWSName = LRSICom.Value
Set RelSh = Worksheets(strWSName)

Set MRLCryActRange = MRLCry.Range("A:A")

Dim RelRow1 As Long
'RelRow1 = MRLCryActRange.Find(Active1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row

'Set Cry database search range
Dim CryDB_SearhRange As Range
Set CryDB_SearhRange = MRLCry.Range("A4:XF4")

'Find relevant Country's column based on Relevant sheets cell information 
CryDB1 = CryDB_SearhRange.Find(RelSh.Cells(4, "AA").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Column

'Check the results in textbox against the relevant database column
If MRLCry.Cells(RelRow1, CryDB1).Value < NewMRL1.Value Then MsgBox ("Result 1 above limit of Country" & MRLCry.Range("A4:XF4").Value)

End Sub
```

I expect it to do nothing when the results is below the limit but should give the message box if the results is above the limit.... currently it give the message box when the result is above below equal to or even blank...

Comment: The bug almost certainly involves details which we have no knowledge of. You are basically asking us why unspecified values are contrary to your unstated expectations. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like `On Error Resume Next` is hidden in your Sub. In your posted code `RelRow1` will be 0, always, which would throw an error if you use it with the `Worksheet.Cells()` method...

Comment: I advise you to shorten the bulk of text significantly. It will help getting help a lot. Let the code do the talking, you just tell us what you expect and what/where the problem is

Comment: fully understand that it might be to little info for what is actually expected is there a way in which i can forward you the workbook and then just refer to the relevant sections to make the understanding easier?

Comment: Tim - I need the system to check a result against a relevant database which have different actives with different limits. If result is below the relevant active's limit then it should give me a message box stating above limit if result is below it should just carry go ahead without doing anything.

Comment: Nacorid - thank you for your advice! i have just checked and if you do not populate the active1 from which the relrow1 is retrieved then it gives you the if false option - any aditional ideas? however if the relrow1 are identified it gives the false positive

Comment: To tag on to what @Nacorid said, when you execute `If MRLCry.Cells(RelRow1, CryDB1).Value < ...` `RelRow1` is set to `0` because that's the default value VBA gives to a `Long`. Right after you declare `RelRow1`, there is a _commented out_ line that assigns a value to it, but it's not actually being executed, so it remains `0`.

Comment: Nacorid! OK so It seems as though he sees the value in the textbox (NewMRL1) as text and not as a numeric value... how do i change it that it sees the text as number and not text?

Comment: Additionally, either code is missing from what you've posted you've got some Global variables going on, or you don't have `Option Explicit` declared. `strWSName`, `MRLCryActRange`, `Active1`, and  `NewMRL1` are all used but not declared. Some are used as if they already have values in them some are assigned values.

Comment: Sorry to be more specific it sees the value in the referred  cell as (against which it needs to check it) as  = 5 but the textbox value read = "3"

Comment: Hi FreeMan - to be very honest i am extremely new to vba so excuse my dumb question... i will google option explicit :) to get back to the relevant names though... strWSName is a worksheet name that comes from a dropdown box... I hear however what you are saying it could actually be removed... MRLCryActRange i will have to put a dim to... Active1 is a dropdownbox and NewMRL1 is a textbox

Comment: @SalomevanZyl Once you have _functional_ code, I'd highly recommend you post it on [CodeReview.se]. As a new VBA programmer you have a lot to learn (we all do!) and you'll learn a lot from a review there. (NOTE: CR is _only_ for working code, not for help getting your code to function properly. It's a great place to learn how to make your functional code _better_.)